# Cessna circling Penrith regularly at night

Tags: general-aviation

For the past year we have had a Cessna circle our local area (Penrith NSW), starting early in the night and often going well into the early hours of the morning. This will happen once a week to fortnight.
On flight tracker, it shows as a Cessna C208.
As a prop plane, it's extremely loud and drones on. My fiancee cannot sleep from the sound.

What could be the cause of this plane flying so loudly in circles, and so often? Finally, how is this legal?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually these questions are simple things like flight training, aerial photography, etc. But looking at the [track](https://fr24.com/C208/2e3d7f3e) it's just endless circles at 5000ft directly over the town. Perhaps a very spiteful divorcee? Try and figure out where they land and call up the airport...

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely an aircraft from NSW Police. I say this because the registration is blocked on FlightRadar24, knowing that they have a fleet of Cessna 208 aircraft based out of Bankstown airport, and because at that area at 5000ft is in what is known as controlled airspace, meaning nobody can fly there without air traffic control permission, which is hard to get when Sydney international airport is open (admittedly it is under curfew from 11pm - 6am with some exceptions).

One of the activities listed on their [website](https://www.police.nsw.gov.au/about_us/organisational_structure/units/aviation_command) is Forward Looking Infra Red scanning, presumably looking for some bad people.

Unfortunately, being a police aircraft, you're unlikely to get it stopped. Consider perhaps contacting your local NSW parliament representative?

Comment: Reminds me of the scene in Captain America: Winter Soldier when infrared scanning satellites and flying guns pretty much presume everyone is a bad guy.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I think you're right, pol air 7 being most likely. This aircraft was billed as being perfect for "remote areas" due to its long fuel range... Unfortunately, police are a law unto themselves so I think your suggestion to write to the local member is the only non violent way to address this. I note a local man was shining a laser at this exact aircraft earlier in the year (and had riot squad bearing down on him very quickly)